# HiveMQ RESTful Authentication Plugin

Tags: java, api, rest, mqtt, hivemq

I am in the process of interfacing to a RESTful API for a proprietary server running internal to my organization. We are using HiveMQ and I have created a simple plugin based on the incredibly useful documentation over at the HiveMQ website.

I have also reviewed the Caching and Non-Blocking philosophy so understand I need to take those into consideration when writing my plugin code.

Our RESTful API has implemented the Spring Security [Remember-Me Auth](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html) and our HiveMQ plugin will use the 'valid' response to provide user Auth in HiveMQ.

My question is are there any *recommended* Java RESTful clients that interface with HiveMQ *best*? Obviously I've searched around and know there are various options. I'm hoping someone with more experience with HiveMQ can provide insight as to what has/hasn't worked better/worse than others.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, all of the HTTP clients for Java should work in an authentication plugin. I know of Apache HTTPClient and Netty that they work perfectly for such tasks. I've created an example plugin [on Github](https://github.com/dobermai/hivemq-rest-auth-plugin) to show a proof of concept with Apache HTTPClient. Although the API is a bit clumsy, HTTPClient is rock solid (and threadsafe!).

As you already stated, proper caching is very important when you want to scale with the mechanism. Blocking is not a problem in the AuthenticationCallback, because HiveMQ needs to wait for the answer of the server which provides the restful API. I personally would use a small timeout, though.

I hope this helps for getting you started with the REST authentication. For more in-depth discussions about that topic, there is also a [HiveMQ Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hivemq).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I ended up using Jersey, which has been working so far. I can authenticate with our backend server and HiveMQ will allow/deny based on that result. I'll take a look at the HiveMQ Google Group.

Comment: If anyone is interested: I wrote a small blog post about that topic here: http://forkbomb-blog.de/2014/bringing-mqtt-authentication-and-rest-together